# MySQL foreign key name, what is it?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize, a nodejs ORM for mysql. Using mysql workbench I made an EEM diagram and pushed that design into the db, so far so good.

Now in Sequelize I have to tell it what the design of the DB looks like, part of that is telling it what foreign keys are called.

In Workbench there is a `foreign key` tab in the table`there are variables formatted like`fd_positions_tradingPLan1` but I never name that, in fact in my EEM diagram I have

[image]

Then if I go to that `foreign keys` tab at the bottom I get this. I am confused as to exactly what I should tell the ORM the foreign key is...

[image]

Comment: if you don't name the FK when creating them, the engine will auto-generate a name for you - that's the name you're seeing

Comment: So those are those the columns in the db then? When I pull up the table I don't see them. I dragged made the relationships with the EEM diagram so maybe they were input. However, I did remove some of the FK's because in some instances they were adding 4 FK's per table when I really just needed one.

Comment: `fd_positions_tradingPLan1` and `fk_positions_users1` are your fk keys. They are not columns. The names in your first photo are the columns

Comment: Oh, so the FK's don't show in the columns then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take your `positions` Table as reference. To build your model on sequelize you have to do the following:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Position = sequelize.define('Position', { // this is the name that you'll use on sequelize methods, not what you have on your db
    // define your columns like this:
    tradeName: { //the name of the variable that you'll use on sequelize and js
      field: 'trade_name', //the actual name of your column on the table
      type: DataTypes.STRING(128) // the data type
    },
    // .......
    // for your foreignKeys you have to define the column like your other attributes.
    userId: {
      field: 'user_id',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'positions', //this is the name of your table on the database
    underscored: true, // to recognize the underscore names
    createdAt: 'created_at', //
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  });

  //now for your association let's say that you defined your USER table like this example.
  Position.associate = (models) => {
    // on the foreignKey value, youhave to put the same that you define above, and on the db.
    Position.belongsTo(models.User, { as: 'User', foreignKey: 'user_id' });
    //depending on your other relations, you are gonna use hasMany, hasOne, belongsToMany
  };

  return Position;
};
```

Sequelize does the association only one way, that means that on this example, you can't query with sequelize from `User` to `Position`, to be able to
have two way association you have to defined on both models.

```
User.associate = (models) => {
  // on this case we use hasMany cause user can have many positions I suppose, if not, use hasOne
  User.hasMany(models.Poisition, { as: 'positions', foreignKey: 'user_id' }); //remeber to use the same foreignKey name
};
```

UPDATE:

`as` is an identfier for Sequelize. Let's say you make two associations for the same model, later when you try to query one of this associations, you can specify the association that you want

```
User.associate = (models) => {
  User.hasMany(models.Poisition, { as: 'positions', foreignKey: 'user_id' }); 
  User.hasMany(models.Poisition, { as: 'customerPositions', foreignKey: 'customer_id' }); 
};

//the actual association call
User.findAll({ 
  include:[{
    model: db.user,
    as: 'positions'
  }, {
    model: db.user,
    as: 'customerPositions'
  }]
})
```

Now for `fk_positions_users1`, this is an identifier for MySQL itself. Sequelize only check for the foreignKey and the models involve. Obviously when Sequelize create the reference, it gives a template name using the table and column name. I tried myself creating a new foreignKey on my table and then updating the model and everything goes fine. You should'nt have problems with that.

Comment: Ok so I have seen examples like this, what does `{as: 'positions'...` do? Then the `...foreignKey: 'user_id'` how does that get my fk's from `fk_positions_users1` from my post into the `Positions`